# Bypassing Gatekeeper in macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, finder, applications, code-signing, gatekeeper

At least until macOS Mojave 10.14.4, a user could run any application on a Mac, signed or not, by right clicking it in Finder and manually selecting Open.

Does this still work for all applications when running macOS Mojave 10.14.5, which has more strict code signing requirements (i.e. [Notarisation](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10192018a))?

Answer (score 2):

Applications that have not gone thru Apple's Notarization process can't be run on Catalina and above.  [According to Apple's information to developers](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/):

> Gatekeeper on macOS helps protect users from downloading and installing malicious software by checking for a Developer ID certificate from apps distributed outside the Mac App Store. Make sure to sign any apps, plug-ins, or installer packages that you distribute to let Gatekeeper know they’re safe to install. And now, you can give users even more confidence in your apps running on macOS Mojave by submitting them to Apple to be notarized.

As of this writing, there hasn't been any published way to go around the Notarization process to run applications.

Update: To address concern about older software not running, Apple [has also stated this in their Support doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution):

> Beginning in macOS 10.14.5, **all new or updated kernel extensions and all software from developers new to distributing with Developer ID must be notarized in order to run.**
>
> Apple recommends that you notarize all of the software that you’ve distributed, including older releases, and even software that doesn’t meet all of these requirements or that is unsigned. Apple’s notary service uses a variety of methods, including telemetry, to determine which of the above rules to relax for preexisting software.

I'm reading that last quote to mean only new software and not existing code.  I think we need more clarification from Apple on what happens to existing applications.

Comment: This, as written, would mean literally nothing coded earlier would ever run again. That's either incorrect or the most sweeping move any OS has ever made. I haven't yet seen the torches & pitchforks at the gates of 1, Infinite Loop, so I'm with the first interpretation.

Comment: No, this is not what I am asking. What I want to know: Is there still a way to bypass Gatekeeper in 10.14.5, as in the past (right click -> Open to run unsigned applications)?

Comment: As of now, there's no known way to bypass Gatekeeper in Catalina.  As the beta has just started a few days ago, we'll have to wait until the software gets into more hands and Apple releases more information.

Comment: That interesting, what about 10.14.5? Can it still be bypassed there after Apple made the mid-cycle changes?

Comment: I haven't seen or read anything from Apple indicating they are changing Gatekeeper in 10.14.5.  [This Apple Support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) still indicates that notarization isn't required.

Comment: Appears that it does break old code.  I've got a pre-notarization app I need to reinstall after my Catalina upgrade and it is hard blocked.  I don't see any way around it.  I'm sure it'll get the notorization added eventually, but I'd really like to be able to install that software *now* and not down the road whenever the next version comes out.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Gatekeeper that's breaking it and not that it is made with, or uses, 32-bit code that doesn't run under Catalina?  Also, is this from a developer that's new to distributing with a specific developer ID (even thought the application might be older, if they used a different developer ID previously) that can block it, too.